# Efficient way to partition list of expressions based on its contents

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, polynomials, functional-style, code-review

I have a list of polynomials `polys` linear in a set of variables `vars`. How do I partition the list based on successive dependence on `vars`?

More concretely, suppose that here is my list of polynomials in three variables:

```
polys = {x, 2 + x + y + z, y, 2 + x + y, 2 + x, -1 + y, y + z, z};
vars = {x, y, z};
```

I need a fast, functional way to partition this list, so that the first group depends only on `x`, the next group only on `x` and `y`, the next group only on `x`, `y` and `z`, ... and so on...

Here is my function that does it:

```
notFreeQ[a_] := Not[FreeQ[#, a]] &

partit[polys_, vars_] := 
  Reverse[First@Last@Reap[
    Fold[Complement[#1, Sow[Select[#1, notFreeQ[#2]], "selected"]] &,
      polys, Reverse[vars]], "selected"]]

partit[polys, vars]

(* {{x, 2 + x}, {-1 + y, y, 2 + x + y}, {2 + x + y + z, y + z, z}} *)
```

I believe there should be a more efficient functional way of achieving my task.  In particular, I do not like how I have to use `Sow`/`Reap` on the polynomials that satisfy the criteria, only to discard the actual result of the function `Fold`.  I am also unhappy with using `Complement` to select the remaining polynomials since it is inefficient.

Can someone help me do a better job partitioning the list of polynomials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't "functional", but using `GroupBy[]` for filtering along with `Sow[]`/`Reap[]` works quite well:

```
partit[polys_List, vars_List] := Module[{init = polys, tmp},
    Reap[Do[tmp = GroupBy[init, SubsetQ[Take[vars, k], Variables[#]] &];
            Sow[tmp[True], "selected"];
            init = tmp[False],
            {k, Length[vars]}], "selected"][[-1, 1]]]
```

Test:

```
polys = {x, 2 + x + y + z, y, 2 + x + y, 2 + x, -1 + y, y + z, z};

partit[polys, {x, y, z}]
   {{x, 2 + x}, {y, 2 + x + y, -1 + y}, {2 + x + y + z, y + z, z}}

partit[polys, {y, z, x}]
   {{y, -1 + y}, {y + z, z}, {x, 2 + x + y + z, 2 + x + y, 2 + x}}

partit[polys, {z, x, y}]
   {{z}, {x, 2 + x}, {2 + x + y + z, y, 2 + x + y, -1 + y, y + z}}
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to assemble *appropriate* criteria in order to search for the appropriate polys each time, store them, remove them from the list and continue until all appropriate criteria are exhausted; it uses `Fold` for the main loop; it still uses `Complement` to remove successful hits from the list (I don't know if one can refrain from using it unless a more involved data structure is used for storing the polys); it uses `Cases` to select the *appropriate* polys each time but it could switch to using `Select` easily; `Join` is used to assemble output but `Flatten` can be also used. All in all, I don't know if it's a better solution than the one proposed but I enjoyed writing it.

```
polys = {x, 2 + x + y + z, y, 2 + x + y, 2 + x, -1 + y, y + z, z};
vars = {x, y, z};

(* successive groups of included vars *)
sucn = FoldList[Flatten[{##}] &, Sequence @@ TakeDrop[vars, 1]]

(* successive groups of excluded vars *)
sucx = Complement[vars, #] & /@ sucn

(* successive group pairs of included/excluded variables *)
sucg = Transpose[{sucn, sucx}]

(* select polys that contain some (or all) of the included vars 
   and do not contain (any of) the excluded vars *)

fsel = Function[{poly, included, excluded}, 
  And[
    Or @@ (MemberQ[poly, #] & /@ included), 
    Not[Or @@ (MemberQ[poly, #] & /@ excluded)]]];

(*
   this works too 
   fsel = Function[{poly, included, excluded}, 
     And[
       Or @@ (MemberQ[poly, Alternatives @@ included]), 
       Not[Or @@ (MemberQ[poly, Alternatives @@ excluded])]]];
*)

(* correctly recognize monomials *)
monomialQ = MemberQ[vars, #] &;
self[poly_?monomialQ, included_, excluded_] := fsel[{poly}, included, excluded]

(* account for the rest of the cases of polys *)
self[poly_, included_, excluded_] := fsel[poly, included, excluded]

(* the main event *)
Fold[
  With[{nd = #2[[1]], xd = #2[[-1]]},
    With[{sel = Cases[#1[[1]], pattn_ :> pattn /; self[pattn, nd, xd]]},
      {Complement[#1[[1]], sel], Join[#1[[-1]], {sel}]}]
     ] &, {polys, {}}, sucg][[-1]]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

When `vars = {y, z, x}` the output is

> [image: Blockquote]

When `vars = {z, x, y}` the output is

> [image: Blockquote]